# Working with a range within an array in Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, min, irvine32

I have written some code for an assignment involving Assembly, and one part of the assignment involves finding the minimum value between two user inputted indexes (I and J).  For the life of me I can not get it to work as the loop does not iterate properly and I cannot figure out why.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
MinValues PROC
mov eax, PosI   ;getting difference between i and j
sub PosJ, eax
mov eax, PosJ
Call WriteInt
mov IJDiff, eax
call crlf

mov ecx, IJDiff
LEA esi, Vector
add esi, PosI
add esi, PosI
add esi, PosI
add esi, PosI
mov eax, [esi]
mov MinNum, eax
NextMin:
    mov eax, [esi]
    call WriteInt
    cmp eax, MinNum
    jl Minimum
    add esi, 4
    Loop NextMin
ret
Minimum: mov MinNum, eax
    ;add esi, 4
    ret
MinValues ENDP
```

Comment: I don't see your declaration for `IJDiff`, so this isn't a [mcve].  But just use a debugger to single-step, and look at what happens when you find a new minimum candidate.  Also, are you sure `WriteInt` doesn't clobber `eax`?  I know Irvine32 is unusual and actually preserves most registers (so I think your use of `ecx` as a loop counter in a loop with function calls is safe.)

Comment: what is your output? WriteInt procedure may stomp eax

Comment: main issue seems to be you return on the first array entry that is less than the first entry. Also, "loop" doesn't decrement ecx so you don't terminate your loop in any normal way.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey loop decrements ECX by 1 and then checks if ECX is zero and then branches (or not) appropriately. Loop is effectively `dec ecx` `jnz looptarget`

Comment: WriteInt was my way of seeing the output, wont be in the final code, and my output starts one element later than it should, and ends earlier than it should on the range (ie a range of 3-10 might look at 4-7).  I'm unsure about what you mean by "doesn't decrement," I thought ecx was the number of times the loop would iterate and would handle automatically?

Comment: Did you solve this? Sorry for distraction about ecx but as soon as you "jl Minimum" the loop is done. You need a loop after Minimum label.